# Odoo - Get single first object from many2one

Tags: python, odoo

I have a class called cmms.history and cmms.equipment and I want to display first element from cmms.history assigned to cmms.equipment, but I have following error "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

```
class cmms_history(osv.osv):
_name = 'cmms.history'
_description = 'CMMS History'
_columns = {
    'equipment_id': fields.many2one('cmms.equipment','Unit of work ref', required=True),
    'customer': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Customer',required=True),
    'start_date': fields.date("Start Date"),
    'end_date': fields.date("End Date"),        

}    
cmms_history()

class cmms_equipment(osv.osv):
_name = "cmms.equipment"
_description = "equipment"
_inherit = ['mail.thread','ir.needaction_mixin','cmms.history']  
_columns = {
    'main_location': fields.function(_last_name,type='many2one', string='Location',  readonly = True),

}
  def last_location(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None): 
    return self.pool.get('cmms.history').browse(cr, uid, ids)   
cmms_equipment()
```

and I want to display the customer from the history on the equipment class.

Thanks.

Comment: In which class 'main_location' field is defined? The field 'main_location' is defined of type 'char' and you are returning a browse record, which doesn't make sense. Please provide proper code structure.

Comment: @HardikPatadia Hi my appologies, Ive uploaded wrong pice of code.

Comment: Are you aware of field of type "Many2one" .. example fields.many2one("cmms.history",string="History"). Also you are trying to define the function named "_last_name", but I don't find the definition of that function and what is the use of function "last_location".

Comment: Include the full traceback into the question.